# Solr's MoreLikeThis: how to use a float number in the mlt.fl?

Tags: solr

I really would like to use a float field to find a document's MoreLikeThis documents. However, from what i know i can only use string fields for mlt.fl? What I meant is to use a unique id of a document to find its MoreLikeThis result where mlt.fl field is expected to be a floating point number. Is there a way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? If so, please can you share.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prefer `myfield` field to be close to 10 (for example), boost according to:

`&bf="dist(1, myfield, 0, 10, 0)^2"`

From http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#Using_FunctionQuery

---

**Update:** Seems like MoreLikeThisHandler doesnt support boost functions as you would have wanted. Try extracting the [interesting terms](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThisHandler#Params) with boosts from the MLT handler and then use them on a regular search handler like Dismax.

Comment: I just tried this, but it's actually not working...What I meant is to use a unique id of a document to find its MoreLikeThis result where mlt.fl field is expected to be a floating point number. Let me update my question in the post as well.

Comment: After researching a whole afternoon, I think the MoreLikeThis handler doesn't support bf param...

Comment: Try my new suggestion and see how it performs. Also I used Manhattan distance as I guess it uses only adddtion as opposed to squares and roots for Euclidian. You can also find some function that is maximum at x and tapers off the farther you get from x, dont know how slow that would get.

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work...SimilarPriceRating is a string i converted from int. Say rating is 1, then SimilarPriceRating is "0 1 2"

       <str name="mlt.qf">
         Title^0.5 Manu^5.0 cat^10.0 
       </str>
       <str name="mlt.fl">Title,Manu,cat</str>
       <int name="mlt.count">12</int>
       <int name="mlt.mintf">1</int>
       <int name="mlt.mindf">1</int>
       <str name="mlt.interestingTerms">SimilarPriceRating</str>
       <bool name="mlt.boost">true</bool>